# bring all categories of data using where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two related tables, data(no, name, citycode, age) and city(code, city)

Table city

```
  +------+------------+
  | code | city       |
  +------+------------+
  | A1   | Jakarta    |
  | A2   | Bali       |
  | A3   | Semarang   |
  | A4   | Surabaya   |
  | C1   | Dili       |
  | C2   | Jayapura   |
  | C3   | Yogyakarta |
  | C4   | Bandung    |
  +------+------------+
```

Table Data

```
+----+--------+----------+------+
| no | name   | citycode | age  |
+----+--------+----------+------+
|  1 | Ony    | A3       |   27 |
|  2 | Abri   | A3       |   28 |
|  3 | Denny  | C4       |   27 |
|  4 | Febri  | C1       |   27 |
|  5 | Galih  | C3       |   28 |
|  6 | Yulia  | A2       |   26 |
|  7 | Zening | A1       |   25 |
+----+--------+----------+------+
```

I want to count the number of employees who are age 27 by city

my query :

```
 select city.city , count(data.name) as Nmb_of_employees
 from city
 left join
 data on data.citycode = city.code
 where data.age = 27
 group by city.city;
```

The result

```
+----------+------------------+
| city     | Nmb_of_employees |
+----------+------------------+
| Bandung  |                1 |
| Dili     |                1 |
| Semarang |                1 |
+----------+------------------+
```

but the result I want is like this

```
+------------+------------------+
| city       | Nmb_of_employees |
+------------+------------------+
| Jakarta    |               0  |
| Bali       |               0  |
| Semarang   |               1  |
| Surabaya   |               0  |
| Dili       |               1  |
| Jayapura   |               0  |
| Yogyakarta |               0  |
| Bandung    |               1  |
+------------+------------------+
```

what query should I use for the results as above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `WHERE` clause which causes to filter out records which has employee of age `27` only. `SUM(age = 27)` is a mysql specific statement only which basically summed up the boolean result of the expression. It can be further modified into using `CASE` which is a more RDBMS friendly, `SUM(CASE WHEN age = 27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

```
SELECT  a.City, IFNULL(SUM(age = 27), 0) Nmb_of_employees 
FROM    city a
        LEFT JOIN Data b
            ON a.code = b.cityCode
GROUP   BY a.City
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d6ca/2)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the 'age' check inside the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT city.city , count(data.name) AS Nmb_of_employees
  FROM city
       LEFT JOIN data 
              ON data.citycode = city.code 
             AND data.age = 27
 GROUP BY city.city;
```

Otherwise you correctly get the table (with blanks) but then filter out the blanks with your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT city,count(name) FROM city m_t3 LEFT JOIN data m_t4 ON 
   age =27 
   AND m_t3.code = m_t4.citycode
  GROUP BY city